# Segmentation fault at ./

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm relatively new to **`C`** and I'm starting to work with threads and the command line; I just need help with a bit of debugging and error handling. I've run into a segmentation fault every time I try and process the code. It works fine if there is an argument for `argv[1]`. However, when trying to catch any errors, such as only entering "./example" and nothing else, it finds a segmentation fault.

I have tried variations of the following code to no avail, including looking to see if `argc < 1`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   pthread_t worker1;
   int in;
   
   if(arv[1] == NULL){
      printf("ERROR HERE");
   }else{
      in = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
   }

   if(*endptr > in || *endptr == in){
      printf("please eneter a number larger than zero");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }else{
      pthread_create(&worker1, NULL, worker, &in);
      pthread_join(worker1, NULL);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Below is the current code which I am using, I'm pretty sure it's something small that I'm overlooking. I have never used `strtol` before and was using `atoi` before, I have heard it's a better practice to do this. I'm relatively sure the error is in the code provided as when I test the thread function, it works fine; if more is needed please let me know!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   pthread_t worker1;
   int in = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);

   if(*endptr > in || *endptr == in){
      printf("please eneter a number larger than zero");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }else{
      pthread_create(&worker1, NULL, worker, &in);
      pthread_join(worker1, NULL);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When there are no command-line arguments, what exactly do you expect `strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10)` to do?  `argv[1]` is then not a valid string.  `argc` tells you how many valid elements `argv` has, so that you can avoid such problems.

Comment: *looking to see if argc < 1*. It will never be less than 1 because the program name is the first arg passed in by convention. Try `< 2`.

Comment: @johnBollinger If I'm being honest this is a relatively new syntax for myself, I assumed that if argv[1] was empty it would return NULL or something along those lines (hence the first piece of code). Like I said I may be completely overlooking something here as I'm not 100% sure on the strtol syntax.

Comment: Well yes, when there are no command line arguments, `argv[1]` (but not necessarily `argv[2]`) contains a null pointer.  So then I guess the question is what you expected `strtol(NULL, &endptr, 10)` to do, when a null pointer, by definition, does not point to anything.

Comment: Some advice: When you tried `argc < 1` and it didn't work it sounds like you gave that up without understanding why it didn't work. Instead you should have debugged it (as you should do for any other unexpected behaviour). A debugger is the tool for that. You could have run it in the debugger and then looked at why your condition was not catching the problem as you expected it to.

Comment: `endptr` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access an array without doing any kind of bounds checking first:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   pthread_t worker1;
   int in = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
...
```

Who is to say that `argv[1]` exists? Certainly not your program, because it doesn't check that condition first. Add a check on `argc` to make sure you are getting the number of arguments you expect before trying to use them.

```
  if (argc > 1) {
    int in = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
  }
```